# I am unable to sign in with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-login, android-facebook

I want to login via Facebook in my android app. I have followed the documentation. But problem is I can only login 1 times with admin Facebook id. Next time while I do login with Facebook id an error comes:

> invalid key hash. the key hash does not match any stored key hashes android. Configure your app key at developer.facebook.com

Another thing while I add the package name an dialog box appeared (There was a problem verifying the package name com.app.com.xxxxx on Google Play. Please check the package name and try again.
If your app isn't listed publicly on Google Play yet you can ignore this message.).

Please some one suggest something so that I can over come this problem.

Comment: Did you configure your debug/release key hash in facebook?

Comment: Yes. Debug key has I given. I get it by using of "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64"

Comment: Did you run the application in device from same pc whose debug key hash you have configured?

Comment: Can you please explain once more

Comment: Actually, debug key hash of every pc for same application is different. So, if you run the application from a pc whose debug key hash you have not configured, then the fb may give this error. This error may also occur if you have changed the folder structure of android sdk or something like this.

Comment: how to solve this.

Comment: I create a fresh project but same problem "Your app must be available in every public store in order take your app Live. Make sure the ID com.app.com.appbbwjit is valid or remove the platform until the app is available."

Comment: Please tell me how can I overcome this.

Comment: how to solve this. >> you can again generate debug key hash and add it to the key hashes section in facebook

Comment: I did it but same problem.

Comment: Asking a silly question, but are you saving after adding key hash? Actually, I am not able to get how is this possible.

Comment: yes I update it in facebook developer.

Comment: I am asking that after updating in facebook developer, are you saving the changes made; there is a button for saving the changes at bottom right